# jQuery autocomplete with MySQL and PHP results don't show up

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a problem with the plugin in jQuery it doesn't show me any results up. I dont where I made the mistake?

thats my newJob.php:

```
<form method="post" action="newJob.php">
<span>Customer Name:<input type="text" id="customerName" name="customerName"></span><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitJob" value="Create Job" >
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/startDate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     //autocomplete
     $("#customerName").autocomplete({
       source: "searchCustomer.php",
       minLength: 1
     });                
  });
</script>
```

My searchCustomer.php:

```
<?php
include('classes.php');

$obj = new CompanyDatabase;
$obj->connect_db();
$obj->select_db();

if (isset($_POST['customerName'])) {
$query = $_POST['customerName'];
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT `Customer Name` FROM `job` WHERE `Customer Name` LIKE \"%".$query."%\"");
$array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $array[] = $row['customerName'];
}
echo json_encode ($array); //Return the JSON Array
}
?>
```

Whats wrong with it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure about `SELECT Customer Name` if fields/columns can contain a space, or if you meant `SELECT Customer, Name` as in both Customer AND Name.

Comment: I'd assume `$_POST['customerName'])` is empty since you aren't posting anything, so your query never actually gets executed.

Comment: `Customer Name` and `customerName`  - `$row['customerName'];` ? I'm confused and I shouldn't be.

Comment: I suggest you change your column name to `Customer_Name` and your query to reflect that change.

Comment: I meant 'Customer Name' but I changed it now to Customer_Name

Comment: Also use a prepared statement, pretty please. Anything else is just asking for trouble of the worst kind.

Comment: @adrian_rpl Then if you did that, you will need to change this `$array[] = $row['customerName'];` to `$array[] = $row['Customer_Name'];` - where there's an "action", there is an opposite or equal "reaction" ;-)

Comment: Yes I changed it to $array[] = $row['Customer_Name']; but still the same :( I'm using also a prepared statement now

Comment: @adrian_rpl What is your form input named as, for that field?

Comment: It's called id="customerName"

Comment: @adrian_rpl It needs to be like this `<input type="text" name="customerName" id="customerName">` - `id` alone won't work. It needs to be named, if you did not have that.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I have that already too. I forgot to tell you :/

Comment: @adrian_rpl Actually it's my mistake, I saw that you do have it named. My apologies.

Comment: @adrian_rpl Try changing `LIKE \"%".$query."%\"` to `LIKE '%".$query."%'`

Comment: still the same nothing changed :(

Comment: @adrian_rpl And instead of using `mysql_fetch_assoc` try using `mysqli_fetch_array` in conjunction with `LIKE '%".$query."%'`

Comment: @adrian_rpl Or try also `'%$query%'`

Comment: @adrian_rpl I don't know what else to tell you, sorry.

Comment: I checked if it even sends the post variable and it did. What I believe is wrong that it doesn't return it to the autocomplete function? So how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe MySQL doesn't allow you columns and table names to have spaces beetween names. Are you sure you're using the correct column and table names?